# Export Scrapy data into Google Sheets

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape multiple websites with Scrapy and exporting the data into Google Sheets.
But for doing that, I need to create a list with the data I want, but I want to scrape data from different websites and I think that the only way to do that is with `yield` but it doesn't create a variable.

How can I fix this?

Here is the code I used:

```
import scrapy


class GainesvilleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gainesvillecoins'
    allowed_domains = ['gainesvillecoins.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.gainesvillecoins.com/products/158985/1-oz-american-gold-eagle-coins',
                  'https://www.gainesvillecoins.com/products/158550/1-2-oz-american-gold-eagle-coins',
                  'https://www.gainesvillecoins.com/products/180843/2022-1-4-oz-american-gold-eagle',
                  'https://www.gainesvillecoins.com/products/180331/2021-1-10-oz-gold-american-eagle-brilliant-uncirculated'
                 ]

    def parse(self, response):
        coin_name = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()
        coin_price = response.xpath("//td[2]/text()").extract_first()
        yield {"coin name": coin_name,
               "coin price": coin_price}
```

Comment: You can certainly create a list in your class (`self.information = []`), and then have your `parse` function append stuff to the list.  You can then access that list as `xxx.information`, assuming xxx is your `GainesvilleSpider` object.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/patkle/scrapy-google-sheets-example) example project using google sheets.